# When factoring an equation to find the solution for x, is the non-solution number proof math is invented?

Tags: factoring

Let's say one is factoring an equation. This equation is solved by factoring and upon doing so one is left with x=-1 and x=3 (the specific number does not really matter for the sake of this question). When plugging those values back into the equation the -1 is found to not equal 0, and 3 does, thus 3 is a solution and -1 is not.

This makes me wonder. Does this support the idea that math is invented rather than discovered? (Given that we get some random value that is meaningless...)

Or does this value actually mean something... If so what?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe cannot happen, at least not exactly the way you describe it; "factoring" means replacing an expression with a product of two expressions which it is equal to, and if one of those expressions is zero the product must always be.

However, a situation *like* the one you describe - in which one solution is *extraneous* - can happen in slightly different circumstances. For example, consider the equation

$$\log_3{x} + \log_3(x - 2) = 1$$

By using a property of logarithms, and raising $3$ to the power of both sides, this gives $x^2 - 2x = 3$, which has solutions $x = -1$ and $x = 3$. But, while $x = 3$ does satisfy the original equation, plugging in $x = -1$ requires taking $\log_3(-1)$, which is nonsense.

This doesn't seem to be a reason to believe that math is an invention - but the filter we see it through, and the words we use for it, are. Here, the issue is that the logarithm property we used (that $\log_3x + \log_3y = \log_3(xy)$) isn't correct in exactly the way we usually think of it; it's only true when the relevant logarithms *exist*.

This is a general rule - when you get an apparent solution that isn't an actual solution, it's because you've made a mistake in your reasoning somewhere, sometimes a very subtle one.

Comment: So you are saying that every instance of an extraneous solution is just the result of using the wrong method to solve? I was wondering if maybe that is an example of how math is just, "something that works well" and when it does not we just ignore those cases... Not that it necessarily is the only "real" thing which explains everything...

Comment: @Outsider I'm not sure I would say "the wrong method". Most mathematicians and math instructors would probably agree that the above is the "right" way to solve that logarithmic equation - basically, it's easier to use the almost-correct version of the rule and fix the errors after-the-fact than it is to deal with the perfectly-correct version of the rule from the start. But yes, every instance of an extraneous solution is the result of taking a mathematically incorrect step.

Comment: I think "mathematically incorrect" is a little strong here. In your example, the algebra proves the implication, "If $x$ is a solution to the equation, then either $x=3$ or $x=-1$," which is a perfectly true statement whose converse happens to be false. If you use this implication along with the fact that $x=3$ solves the equation but $x=-1$ does not to give the precise solution set of the equation, you have made no mathematical errors. I would rather say that every instance of an extraneous solution is the result of taking an irreversible step...

Comment: ...and that we are often careless about tracking exactly which algebraic steps are reversible.

Comment: @Micah That's reasonable, except that I'm not sure I would say anyone would describe the conclusion of an algebraic argument as "if $x$ is a solution, then..." unless they were specifically trying to explain why a given solution turned out to be extraneous. While that would be the *mathematically correct* interpretation of the steps, the conventional interpretation is "these are solutions to the equation". In other words, the error is either in the step or in the conventional interpretation; either way, there's a mathematical error.

Answer (score 0):

When such solutions wildy appear but aren't satisfied by original equations these are called extraneous solutions and discarded.

But I don't think they might appear in factoring.